# Margin create from div

Tags: html, css, background

I want to create a header set the header background colour. The header should occupy the full width and start from the top. I wrap up the header with a 'div' and set up the background colour. However, I find there is some margin created and I couldn't remove.
Here is the css:

```
#header_section 
{
    background-color: #052c39;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

And here is the outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Av7.png)

Can any body have an idea how to remove the margin?

Comment: Use developer tools in your browser to see which element the margin is a part of. It could be the body's margin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried:body 
{
    font-family: Lucida Sans,sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;

}
but when I opened the developer tool, I found 8px margin is added automatically:
body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}

Comment: can  you provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

As [jackarms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128362/jackarms) said,  it might be the margin on the body or html tag.

Try using:

```
body {  margin: 0 !important  }
```

Comment: I tried your way, but I still found 8px of margin is added automatically. This is an new project and there are not many elements, but I still couldn't spot the cause of the problem.

Comment: @DennisL Glad to help! If it has solved your problem, could you accept [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234#answer-5235)?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a HTML project first you need to put the css RESET. otherwise you need to do something like this

```
body,ul {
  margin:0; 
}
```